# Button click - redirect to UserControl.cs page in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my project, It consist two page. Those are Form1.cs,myusercontrol1.cs.

Form1 having Button. In Button_click event need to redirect Form1 to myuserontrol1.cs page.

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code1
            var destinationform = new myusercontrol1();
            destinationform.Show();


            // Code2
            myusercontrol1 destinationformobj = new myusercontrol1();
            destinationformobj.Show();
        }
```

But it never redirect to myusercontrol1.cs page

Is this possible to redirect from Form to UserControl page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: User controls are not forms. They can't exist outside a form you need to create  a form and place your control in it and then show that

Comment: @Emad thank you for your reply, Yeah UserControl are not form. Is there any way to do it Or it's impossible?

Comment: It's like to show a single button in the fly! over no form! As far as I know it's impossible. However I had a similar situation where I created a form which was empty and would accept an instance of user control and then render it in it's own space. If you want I can share the idea with you.

Comment: Yes ofcourse @Emad. Could you please give me some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok according to the comments you can do this to solve your problem with a form:

```
public frmUserControl : Form
{
    private UserControl control;

    public frmUserControl(UserControl control)
    {
        this.control = control;
        this.Load += frmUserControl_Load;
    }

    public frmUserControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

You also have to take care of a few things like the size of the new form and the position of your user control inside the form. I tried to find my old code for that but it was too old and I don't have it right now. So I hope it helps :)

Comment: Only possible to add control at run time?

Comment: Well adding a user control to a normal form in design time is a very normal task. Do you want to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your reply . No I want to redirect UserControl.cs page. Its very strange